# Transfer data from one worksheet to another automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I want to transfer data from one Excel worksheet to another automatically. I have tried it with Visual Basic Editor using a command button in Excel. It works successfully, but I want to do it without clicking a command button. When I insert a value from one sheet it should be transfer to another sheet automatically.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Workbook event `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible since the macro or vba needs to have command. Therefore you really need to make a command button to have it work. There won't be any reference to action that the macro or vba could work without a command.